# How to display my timeline of only a particular month in the past?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I want to check everything I posted a particular month many years ago.

I could scroll down all the way, but scrolling all these years takes forever and makes my browser really slow.

How to show my timeline only for a particular month, for instance December 2009?

Answer (score 2):

#### Mouse and click method

1. Go to your timeline
2. Scroll down a bit
3. The menu below appears, just select a year and a month:

[image: Facebook timeline year month]

#### URL method

Replace your id and the year/month then paste it in your browser:

```
https://www.facebook.com/<yourfacebookid>/timeline/2009/12
```

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your timeline.
- Click on **View Activity Log**.
- Scroll down a little bit.

Now you will see years in right hand side. Click on a particular year and it will show you all your activity month wise for that year starting from December.

If you only want see your posts, select **Your Posts** from left hand side options and then select year from right hand side. It will show what you have posted in that particular year month wise starting from December.

Here is direct link for all activity:

```
https://www.facebook.com/user_name/allactivity
```

Change `user_name` with your user name.

Comment: So, no way to select a particular month, for instance January? On a slow computer loading a full year simply does not load, the computer slows down to a crawl well before.

Comment: I didn't find to select particular month. But it works on slow computer also.